# LO Calc is reversing X and Y axes on chart

Tags: charts, libreoffice

I have some data:

```
105604  8
301176  4
497752  3
691704  11
886404  18
1081280 25
1278152 27
1470616 28
1663900 30
1858404 33
2056624 34
2254728 35
2452292 37
2647068 37
2844476 38
3042868 41
3240692 42
3435048 43
3629728 45
3824456 45
4018128 45
4212008 47
4407576 46
4598388 48
4791280 50
4984712 51
5179380 51
5372352 52
5566588 53
5759836 53
5954920 53
6147796 53
6340736 52
6533024 52
6727888 53
6920636 54
7113916 54
7306188 57
7503276 57
7700648 58
7897652 59
8090380 59
8287044 59
8484640 60
8666004 60
8820860 61
8976012 62
9151244 62
9339176 60
9525164 61
9713488 60
9906368 60
10100684    61
10293260    61
10486500    62
10681148    62
10875664    62
11067868    63
11262700    64
11456076    64
11649636    65
11842460    65
12036076    65
12229212    65
12422996    66
12615208    66
12811148    67
13007332    66
13203636    66
13395164    66
13589684    66
13785468    66
13980732    67
14172092    66
14365604    66
14557368    67
14749196    67
14940988    68
15135732    68
15328384    68
15521412    67
15712676    67
15907408    67
16099348    67
16292320    68
16482532    67
16676156    67
16867504    67
17059276    68
17250556    68
17444020    69
17635984    69
17827292    69
18019060    69
18213424    69
```

If I select this two columns in LibreOffice Calc and press the "diagram" button, aka "chart wizard" I will get this:

[image]

**Q:** How can I swap X and Y axes?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not that the axes are switched, you're using the wrong type of chart. The X axis shown is not your second column data, but the sequence number of the record. Change the chart to a scatter chart (XY chart).

Unfortunately, a column-style appearance isn't possible without a workaround, at least not natively. For that, you would need to do something like make every record a separate series and add a Y value of zero for every X value. LO Calc won't make sense of that automatically. You will need to manually define all 95 series.

Here's what it would look like for the first few records:

[image]

Each series would be a 2-row range:

[image]

The chart will look like this:

[image]

That's just the first four records.  Rinse and repeat to include the other 91.  Then you can customize the axis labels, markers, colors, etc. to your liking.